# How to run the flask program from under root (apache2 wsgi)

Tags: flask, apache2, mod-wsgi

I wrote a python program, it works fine if I run it on my computer, but I run it from under app.run(), that is, the user who enters python3 main.py..
But I put it on the server (apache2) and it works quite well, but besides editing the database, an access rights error.. I would like to run it not under www-data of the user and group, but under root, where my bot on aiogram3 that also uses this database.
(Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.2.0 x86_64))

Tried to add

```
user=root group=root threads=5
```

at the end

```
WSGIDaemonProcess hexagonWebSSL python-path=/var/www/thehexagon.online/hexagonWeb user=root group=root threads=5
```

but an error occurs

```
Oct 02 15:18:39 vps.first apachectl[100103]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 23 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/thehexagonHTTP.online-le-ssl.conf:
Oct 02 15:18:39 vps.first apachectl[100103]: WSGI process blocked from running as root.
Oct 02 15:18:39 vps.first apachectl[100100]: Action 'start' failed.
```